# High CPU load of my VPS

Tags: linux, mysql, load-balancing

I use VPS from digitalocean. The configuration is: 8GB RAM, 4 Core Processor, 80GB SSD with cpanel installed. Most visitors are in the site http://www.secretdiarybd.com/bn . Which is on wordpress platform. The Size of the mysql database is currently 80 MB. There are around 250-300 concurrent visitors. The my.cnf file is follows:

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
key-buffer-size                = 256M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP
max-allowed-packet             = 16M

tmp-table-size                 = 128M
max-heap-table-size            = 128M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 128
max-connections                = 100
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 2024
table-open-cache               = 2024

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 256M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 1G
innodb-buffer-pool-instances   = 1
```

Server load is always 30+ and RAM usage is around 20%. How can is reduce the server load? Please note that site and database is optimized.

Comment: Check first what services are making the Server Load go up. It could be your web server, your db, your ssl, maybe your code, or others. There might be other things going on the background. But for sure if its just this one site on this VPS, your specs are more than enough. Again, identify first the bottlenecks. Check logs and run **top**

Comment: Using `top` command it is showing the `php` is using most  resources. and sometimes `mysql` also

Comment: Do you know what type of work is CPU doing? top can you tell if your bottleneck is IO wait or just normal work. Update your question with top output.

Answer (score 1):

Caching on the web server is usually far more effective than caching using a Wordpress plugin. I have a [Wordpress/Nginx caching tutorial for Nginx](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/), but it's possible using Apache as well. This [article goes into microcaching](https://www.nginx.com/blog/benefits-of-microcaching-nginx/), which is helpful if your content changes rapidly. Most Wordpress blogs are fine cached, you just exclude logged in users from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

These values are pretty normal for a site with 200+ concurrent visits. With such traffic, a dedicated server would be recommended.

In the meantime, You can install the free Wordpress plugin named WP Super Cache. Choosing the best configuration may require analyzing your business logic, but you can setup the plugin following these hints:

- **Cache mode** = mod_rewrite mode
- **Compression** = disabled, as it isn't needed in many cases
- **Cache purging** = disabled (the plugin will still automatically clears cache for updated or commented pages);
- **Clear only post/page when a comment is made** = enabled (only if your site is open to comments and comment number isn't show outside the page, for example in a post listing)
- **Clear all page/posts when updated** = disabled (only if your site doesn't show post listings in home page or other pages)
- **Excluded user agents**: delete all from that field, so Search Engines too will see the fast cached version of the site and your PageRank will benefit from that too.